# [GAE]:How to create a JWT to obtain an acces token

Tags: scala, google-app-engine, jwt

I am trying to create a JWT for the authentication of [Googles app engine](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount)

The main issue is that I need to create a signer with `RSA using SHA-256 hashing algorithm`.

The only library I found which supports this is [Nimbus](http://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt) but their signing always uses the already created private key which is of type `RSAPrivateKey`, I need to be able to sign with the private key `String` I obtained from google.

How can I transform the `String` representation of my private key into a `RSAPrivateKey` object?

Comment: I assume that this constraint on how the key is generated is because you're doing it manually, using HTTP to get the OAuth tokens (requiring you to create a valid JWT & encode it to base64 for transport) instead of the Google APIs client library  for Java. Why can you not use the pre-written libraries that Google created to make your life easier?

Comment: You just need to add the .jars that contain `com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential`, `com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport`, `com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory`, etc. ([see the tutorial section "Other" for actual code example][1] that you should adapt) to your web server's java classpath so you can use that method instead of worrying about third party SHA libraries...


  [1]: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests